# Running IRIS for Health in docker container with durable %SYS volume

Tags: docker, intersystems-iris

I'm trying to run IRIS for Health Community Edition container on Mac (Apple chip) as follows

```
docker run --name iris -d --publish 1972:1972 --publish 52773:52773 --volume /<volume-path-on-host>:/<volume-name-in-container> --env ISC_DATA_DIRECTORY=/<volume-name-in-container>/<durable-directory> containers.intersystems.com/intersystems/irishealth-community-arm64:latest-cd
```

but it will error out to start

```
2023-10-17 09:15:29 10/17/23-13:15:29:045 (391) 0 [Utility.Event] Updating configuration files
2023-10-17 09:15:29 10/17/23-13:15:29:219 (391) 0 [Utility.Event] Creating directory /external/durable/ContainerCheck/
2023-10-17 09:15:29 10/17/23-13:15:29:221 (391) 0 [Utility.Event] Executing chown irisowner:irisowner /external/durable/ContainerCheck/
2023-10-17 09:15:29 10/17/23-13:15:29:228 (391) 0 [Utility.Event] Executing cp -fp /usr/irissys/dev/Container/ContainerCheck.sh /external/durable/ContainerCheck/ContainerCheck.sh
2023-10-17 09:15:29 10/17/23-13:15:29:238 (391) 3 [Utility.Event] Error while moving data directories ERROR #5001: Error executing cp -fp /usr/irissys/dev/Container/ContainerCheck.sh /external/durable/ContainerCheck/ContainerCheck.sh: Error:1:
2023-10-17 09:15:29 [ERROR] See the above messages or /external/durable/mgr/messages.log for more information
2023-10-17 09:15:29 [FATAL] Error starting InterSystems IRIS
```

If I do not provide a durable volume, it will start w/o any issues.

Any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's a common problem for Docker Desktop on Mac with VirtioFS that struggle to bind owner of a file between host and container :

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6243

Switching to "gRPC FUSE" solved the problem.